# Downgrade Nexus 6 Android without Factory Image

Tags: android, flashing, nexus6

I need an Android 4.4.2 device to test a tool. Currently I am stuck with a Nexus 6 and would like to know if there is any way of downgrading its Android version without a [factory image](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images), since the lowest available version seems to be 5.0 for the Nexus 6.

EDIT: Emulation is not a solution, because the tool relies on the responsiveness of the application and emulators are very slow in practice.

Comment: How about using cyanogen mod ?

Comment: As far as I've gathered cyanogen mod actually is not just a reskin of Android but actually implements various features such as the security policy differently. As such I doubt that it behaves exactly the same as 4.4.2.

Comment: Yea, it does so, but the working is almost the same. I had it

Answer (score 0):

Probably not since there are no drivers for KitKat as it started with Lollipop. But you would have to find a custom ROM of KitKat for the Nexus 6 (shamu).

Depending on what type of tool you are testing, I would suggest using the device emulator of Android Studio to get Android 4.4.2.

Comment: The tool performs dynamic analysis of an app. Emulation does not work, because the emulator is so slow that when analysis fetches the current GUI state, sometimes the emulator is in a transitional state with no GUI being displayed. This leads to analysis crashing.

Answer (score 0):

Their are, 2 ways to accomplish what you are upto.

1. **Use custom Roms**
   (As I have already mentioned)
2. **Use Emulators** you get custom emulators of nexus phones in android studio. Download them. It's API level 19
   But, since you need responsiveness, go with the custom Roms thing. You can try [Cyanogen Unofficial](http://www.cyanogenmodroms.com/2014/01/unofficial-ports.html).

Comment: All that matters to me is restriction to API level 19 i.e. 4.4.2 and exactly the same log formatting i.e. logcat output etc. are identical.

Comment: Both will serve your purpose

Comment: That technically looks good, but I can't seem to find a legacy version for Nexus 6. On the unofficial page you posted only Nexus One is listed. In the same domain if you simply go to the page of Nexus 6 the only available version seems to be based on 6.0.